# How to count the number of elements of an arraylist with a certain term/word?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist of sentences as follows-

```
List<String> allDocuments= new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("my name is john what is your name");
    list.add("hello how are you");
    list.add("no name entered");
    list.add("who are you");
```

As you can see in two elements the word 'name' and 'you' appears. How do I get the number of elements each word appears in? so the end result would be

name = 2 elements

my= 1 elements

you=2 elements

So far I'm stuck on the number of times each word appears in a single element instead of how many elements have the each word.

```
List<String[]> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String s : allDocuments) {
            list2.add(s.split(" "));
        }
        ;
        for (String[] s : list2) {
        Map<String, Integer> wordCounts = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();

        for (String word : s) {
            Integer count = wordCounts.get(word);
            if (count == null) {
                count = 0;
            }
            wordCounts.put(word, count + 1);
        }

        for (String key : wordCounts.keySet()) {

             System.out.println(key + ": " + wordCounts.get(key));

        }
    }
```

Would appreciate the help, thanks!

Comment: Hint: you want us to spent our time to help you. So you please spend the time to format your code in a more readable fashion. You know, this code wouldn't even compile, because you are declaring list2 twice. And btw: list2 is a pretty nothing-telling name. Use names that say what the object "means"; like "splittedWords" or whatever.

Comment: @GhostCat sorry that was an error on my part copying the code over and formatting it.

Comment: Dont apologize; just go and fix it ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Map<String, Integer> wordCounts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

//making list of all words
for (String s : allDocuments)
  for ( String s2 : s.split(" "))
    if( ! wordCounts.containsKey(s2) )
        wordCounts.put(s2,0);

//counting occurence of all words in whole strings
for (String k : wordCounts.keySet())
  for (String s : allDocuments)
    if(s.indexOf(k) != -1)
      wordCounts.put(k, wordCounts.get(k)+1);
```

Comment: this seems to be what I needed! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I hope this can help you. My code have java 8 syntax:

```
 ArrayList<String> allDocuments = new ArrayList<String>();
    allDocuments.add("my name is john");
    allDocuments.add("hello how are you");
    allDocuments.add("no name entered");
    allDocuments.add("who are you");

    HashMap<String, Integer> words = new HashMap<>();

    for (String sentence : allDocuments) {
        String[] sentenceSpli = sentence.split(" ");
        for (String word : sentenceSpli) {
            //If my map contain the word I add 1 otherwise add it
            if (words.containsKey(word)) {
                words.put(word, words.get(word) + 1);
            } else {
                words.put(word, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    //Print result
    for (String key : words.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(key + " : " + words.get(key) + " time(s)");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fix your code instead of rewriting it entirely, here is how to proceed:

First, store the words of each *document* in `Set`s instead of arrays to prevent duplicates:

```
List<Set<String>> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
for (String s : allDocuments) {
    list2.add(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(s.split(" "))));
}
```

Then simply move the `wordCounts` declaration and printing outside the loop, and convert the loop to iterate over `Set<String>`'s instead of `String[]`'s:

```
Map<String, Integer> wordCounts = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (Set<String> s : list2) {
    for (String word : s) {
        Integer count = wordCounts.get(word);
        if (count == null) {
            count = 0;
        }
        wordCounts.put(word, count + 1);
    }
}

for (String key : wordCounts.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(key + ": " + wordCounts.get(key));
}
```

Now the output is correct:

```
what: 1
name: 2
is: 1
john: 1
your: 1
my: 1
how: 1
are: 2
hello: 1
you: 2
no: 1
entered: 1
who: 1
```

You weren't that far from a solution in fact ;-)

(note that the iteration over the `wordCounts` can be improved by iterating over the `entrySet()` but I didn't want to alter your code too much)

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the list, then split each sentence up by spaces. Then, iterate through each word and see if the words match what you are looking for.

```
List<String> allDocuments = new ArrayList<String>();
allDocuments.add("my name is john");
allDocuments.add("hello how are you");
allDocuments.add("no name entered");
allDocuments.add("who are you");

int name = 0, my = 0, you = 0;
for (String msg : allDocuments){
    for (String word : msg.split(" ")){
        if (word == "name"){
            name++;
        }
        if (word == "my"){
            my++;
        }
        if (word == "you"){
            you++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I would need to check each word and number of elements it appears in. The arraylist will have more added and removed to it down the line.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you're trying to say. Why won't this work?

Answer (score 0):

create a map wich defines the words with the coincidences... something like `Map<String, Integer>`

Example:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("my name is john");
    list.add("hello how are you");
    list.add("no name entered");
    list.add("who are you");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(processList(list));
    }

    private static Map<String, Integer> processList(List<String> list) {
    Map<String, Integer> coincidences = new HashMap<>();
    for (String string : list) {
        String[] sp = string.split(" ");
        for (String string2 : sp) {
        if (coincidences.get(string2) == null) {
            coincidences.put(string2, 1);
        } else {
            coincidences.put(string2, coincidences.get(string2) + 1);
        }
        }
    }
    return coincidences;
    }
```

this will give a map like:

> {how=1, no=1, are=2, name=2, is=1, john=1, hello=1, entered=1, my=1,
>   you=2, who=1}

which is a very optimal representation of the information you need

Comment: This solution counts "_name_" too much in the OP's example as his first sentence contains it twice.

Answer (score 0):

By the split you are doing, the List contains all instances of every word. So, I would recommend using a Set to store the single words to be counted:

```
Set<String> words = new HashMap<>();
for (String s : allDocuments) {
    words.addAll(Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")));
}
```

Then use this set and iterate over your allDocuments for every entry:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> wordcount = new HashSet<>();
for (String word : words) {
    int count = 0;
    for (String entry : allDocuments) { 
         if (entry.contains(word)) {
             count++;
        }
    }
    wordcount.put(word, count);
}
```

I don't have the possibilty to test this right now, but something similar to this should do the trick.

Greets

Comment: With this solution, "your" counts as a "you" too.